# In which verse number of Gita, Krishna tells about sankhya yoga?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, sankhya

**In which verse number of Gita**, Krishna tells about sankhya yoga?

Especially verse number of any verse in which He tells that He is sankhya yoga among all yogas, or if in any verse he praises sankhya yoga as best path or some other praise of sankhya yoga.

Answer (score 4):

Ch 5. verse 4: talks about Samkhya and Yoga branch of philosophy.

Ch 7. verse 13: talks about three Gunas (concept of Samkhya).

Ch 10. verse 26: mentions sage Kapila, one of the founders of Samkhya doctrine.

> अश्वत्थः सर्ववृक्षाणां देवर्षीणां च नारदः।
>
> गन्धर्वाणां चित्ररथः सिद्धानां कपिलो मुनिः।।10.26।।
>
> Of all trees, I am the Pipal-tree; and of the divine seers, Narada; of the Gandharvas (the celestial musicians), Citraratha; of the perfected ones, the sage Kapila (the propounder of the Yoga system called Sankhya).

Ch 13. verse 5: this entire verse talks about the Samkhya concept.

This list is not exhaustive. There could be other verses as well.

Answer (score 1):

**[SB 8.24.55](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/24/55)**

> The Supreme Personality of Godhead thus explained to King Satyavrata
>   the spiritual science known as sāṅkhya-yoga, the science by which one
>   distinguishes between matter and spirit [in other words, bhakti-yoga],
>   along with the instructions contained in the Purāṇas [the old
>   histories] and the saṁhitās. The Lord explained Himself in all these
>   literatures.

**[SB 10.85.39](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/85/39)**

> King Bali said: Obeisances to the unlimited Lord, Ananta, the greatest
>   of all beings. And obeisances to Lord Kṛṣṇa, the creator of the
>   universe, who appears as the impersonal Absolute and the Supersoul in
>   order to disseminate the principles of sāṅkhya and yoga.

**[SB 11.24.1](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/11/24/1)**

> Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa said: Now I shall describe to you the science of
>   Sāṅkhya, which has been perfectly established by ancient authorities.
>   By understanding this science a person can immediately give up the
>   illusion of material duality.